# Filemerge with git - It's all gone horribly wrong

Tags: git, filemerge

Following [this tutorial](http://www.jotlab.com/2009/11/16/how-to-use-filemerge-with-git-as-a-diff-tool-on-osx/) to the letter, whenever I now run a diff, I get the following:

```
~~$ git diff
fatal: cannot exec '/Users/john/git-diff-cmd.sh': Permission denied
external diff died, stopping at footer.php.
```

This is obviously undesirable!! How can I fix it, and how can I get Filemerge and GIT to play nice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your script has to be executable:

```
chmod u+x '/Users/john/git-diff-cmd.sh'
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't have execution privileges for your script file. Go to the terminal and type

```
chmod a+x /Users/john/git-diff-cmd.sh
```

and then try running git again.

Comment: user executable should be enough though